# Create ID field with random starting polygon in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile

I have a shapefile composed by parallel strips. The default FID field orders the strips from left to right. I want to create an ID field where strips are ordered from left to right but with the first strip chosen randomly.

Is it possible in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure about a couple of things:
1 - Will this need to be done repeatedly or just once?
2 - How do you want to handle all the FIDs with a lower value than the randomly selected one?

If you can figure out your highest FID number (I'm supposing the lowest is 1), you can generate a random number (ex. [here](http://www.mathgoodies.com/calculators/random_no_custom.html)).
Then just create a separate variable in the polygon table. Use field calculator, python. For the pre-logic script:

```
def ID_Gen(randID, intmin, intmax, FID):
     if FID < randID:
          return intmax - FID
     elif FID > randID:
          return FID - randID +1
     else:
          return randID/randID
```

[image]